# Server Design and Implementation

Tags: java, c++

I've work in embedded systems and systems programming for hardware interfaces 
to date.  For fun and personal knowledge, recently I've been trying to learn more about server programming after getting my hands wet with Erlang.  I've been going back and thinking about servers from a C++/Java prospective, and now I wonder how scalable systems can be built with technology like C++ or Java.

I've read that due to context-switching and limited memory, a per-client thread handler isn't realistic.  Usually a thread-pool is created and a mix of worker-threads and asynchronous I/O is used to handle requests.  I wonder, first of all, how does one determine the thread pool size?  Does one simply have to measure and find the optimal balance?  Eventually as the system scales then perhaps more than one server is needed to handle requests.  How are requests managed across mulitple servers handling a large client base?

I am just looking for some direction into where I might be able to read more and find answers to my questions.  What area of computer science would I look into for more information in this area?  Are there any design patterns for this area of computing?

Comment: I appreciate this question but maybe it is four or five questons wrapped into one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for C++ I've used boost::asio, it's very modern C++, and quite plesant to work with. Also the C++0x network libraries will be based on ASIO's implementation, so it's valuable knowledge.

As for designs 1thread per client, doesn't work, as you've already learned. And for high performance multithreading the best number of threads seems to be CoresX2, but for servers, there is lots of IO per request, which means lots of idle waiting. And from experience, looking at Apache, MySQL, and Oracle the amount of threads is about CoresX10 for database servers, and CoresX40 for web servers, not saying these are the ideals, but they seem to be patterns of succesful systems, so if your system can be balanced to work optimally with similar numbers atleast you'll know your design isn't completely lousy.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is too general to have a nice answer.  The answer depends greatly on the context, on how much processing any one Thread does, on how rapidly requests arrive, on the CPU family being used, on the web container being used, and on many other factors.

Answer (score 1):

[C++ Network Programming: Mastering Complexity Using ACE and Patterns](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE/book1/) and
[C++ Network Programming: Systematic Reuse with ACE and Frameworks](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE/book2/) are very good books that describe many design patterns and their use with the highly portable [ACE](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html) library.

Answer (score 1):

Like Lothar, we use the [ACE](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html) library which contains reactor and proactor patterns for handling asynchronous events and asynchronous I/O with C++ code.  We use sizable worker thread pools that grow as needed (to a configurable maximum) and shrink over time.

One of the tricks with C++ is how you are going to propagate exceptions and error situations across network boundaries (which isn't handled by the language).  I know that there are ways with .NET to throw exceptions across these network boundaries.

One thing you may consider is looking into SOA (Service Oriented Architecture) for dealing with higher level distributed system issues.  ACE if really for running at the bare metal of the machine.